# Android BroadcastReceiver, auto run service after reboot of device

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, manifest, reboot

Hello i am writing an application, which is when the phone reboot, the service will auto start instead of click on the application.

Here is my code for

**BootCompleteReceiver.java**

```
package com.example.newbootservice;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;  
import android.content.Context;  
import android.content.Intent;    

public class BootCompleteReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {   

    @Override  
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {  

        Intent service = new Intent(context, MsgPushService.class);  
        context.startService(service);   

    }  

}
```

**MsgPushService.java**

```
package com.example.newbootservice;

import android.app.Service;  
import android.content.Intent;  
import android.os.IBinder;   
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MsgPushService extends Service {  


    @Override  
    public void onCreate() {  
        super.onCreate();    
    }  

    @Override  
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {  

        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return Service.START_STICKY;  
    }  

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Destroy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override  
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {  
        return null;  
    }  
}
```

**MainActivity.java**   (not sure whether i need this)

```
package com.example.newbootservice;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        startService(new Intent(getBaseContext(), MsgPushService.class));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.newbootservice"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <service android:name=".MsgPushService"/>

        <receiver android:name=".BootCompleteReceiver">  
            <intent-filter>     
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />  
            </intent-filter>  
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I want the service to be started automatically after reboot instead of starting it manually.

Answer (score 10):

You forgot about the permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 8):

Though all the above answers were correct, however from `Android Oreo` they put some limitation on Background Services.

Check [Background Execution Limits](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html) to know more about background limits in Android O.

You can't start a Service directly from BroadCastReceiver when the application is in the background.

However, you can start a foreground service from the receiver by calling `startForegroundService()` or use [JobIntentService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/JobIntentService.html) as there is no such limitation with JobIntentService.

Comment: i am unable to implement with foreground service, do you mind explaining with example

Comment: That means as that of Oreo, we cannot start the broadcastreceiver service when the app is restarted when it is in background right? is there any work around?

Answer (score 2):

Use this code on your Broadcast Receiver class:

```
if ("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equals(intent.getAction())) {
   Intent service = new Intent(context, MsgPushService.class);  
    context.startService(service);  
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

also try these permissions,it may help you .ifyou are using htc phones then these permissions are required

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
```