# How can I always display a Notification icon after I restart mobile phone?

Tags: android

I am using the following code to add an icon to Notification status, it works well, it always display even if I exit the app.

But the icon disappears whenever I restart mobile phone, what can I do to make the icon always display even if I restart phone ?

```
private void showNotification() {

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
    this.getSystemService(android.content.Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);


    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.smsforward,"My System", System.currentTimeMillis());


    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT; 
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;

    CharSequence contentTitle = "My System Title"; 
    CharSequence contentText = "My System Title content"; 

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SMSMain.class); 

    PendingIntent contentItent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, contentTitle, contentText,contentItent);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to listen when the boot is completed and then show same notification again. Here is a simple example.

In your manifest file.

```
<receiver android:name="BootNotificationReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And in your code.

```
 public class BootNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

     // display notification again
     showNotification();// or whatever

      }
    }
```

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thanks! in my mainifest file I have the code          <!-- Broadcast receiver -->
        <receiver android:name="bll.SmsBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>              
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>   , could I add  a new <receiver android:name="BootNotificationReceiver"> ?

Comment: For sure. You may add as much broadcast receivers as you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the device boot up intent and launch the same notification again.

[Android BroadcastReceiver, auto run service after reboot of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385231/android-broadcastreceiver-auto-run-service-after-reboot-of-device)

Answer (score 1):

Declare `Broadcast Receiver` in manifest xml.

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
    {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
            if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED))
            {
                // your code here
            }
        }
    }
```