# Sync Adapter: How do I force re-sync on a failed sync after device was Off and on again?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am using sync adapter to sync between my mobile device to my central server. When I add a record to my sqlite DB on the device, I am using requestSync to sync with  server and it is working well. Even when there is no internet connection with server, I am able to force re-sync later by catching the ParseException  and incrementing syncResult.stats.numParseExceptions in the SyncAdapter's' onPerformSync.

My problem is if i switch-off my device before sync is complete. No sync is attempted when i turn device on again. What can I do to ensure sync is attempted when I turn device on again?

My code:

UI activity --> on Save Button Click event handler

```
ContentResolver.requestSync(createDummyAccount() DatabaseContract.AUTHORITY , settingsBundle);
```

//SyncAdapter -->> onPerformSync()

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();

client.property(ClientProperties.CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 6000);

WebTarget target = client.target(SERVICE_URL);

try {
     String callResult = target
     .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
     .put(Entity.entity(form,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE),
        String.class);
    System.out.println("response: " + callResult);
} catch (ProcessingException pe) {
    syncResult.stats.numIoExceptions++;
    syncResult.delayUntil = 60;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have look on this SO post

[Android BroadcastReceiver, auto run service after reboot of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385231/android-broadcastreceiver-auto-run-service-after-reboot-of-device)

by **Dixit Patel**

and start your service once you received the broadcast receiver. In this you have to register with `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` to receive broadcast

Comment: I am not getting it clear here. You want me to implement a BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: Sorry, but i am a bit confused. I already had a bound service - SyncService - declared in the manifest to instantiate the SyncAdapter. Is this not enough ... or which service will the BroadCast receiver above start?

Comment: the broadcast receiver is to receive the device boot event and then run your service again