# How to send notifications even after reboot?

Tags: java, android

I would like to send notifications when the user doesn't use/open the application after a time period. For example, if the user does not open the application for 1 minute. A notification will be displayed with the message "We miss you".

Comment: Oh my gosh don't support this!!!!111

Comment: Create a cronjob that executes every minute and checks for the running app

Comment: the proper way is to use a server in conjunction. when the user uses the app, you can send something to the server, like the time the app rendered for that user. create a service that checks that whenever u need. if its been that long, send the push. look into onesignal, they do a pretty good job with it

Comment: Create a broadcast receiver just like he did in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14385231/6455501

From there start your service on your BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: thanks. @dr3k I creat the BroadcastReceiver.I have just a problem. How I can send a notification when the apps is close ?

Comment: And serviceStart not work when I put it in "onDestroyx". Why ? What can I do ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Setup a scheduled alarm:
https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms (there is also a example to start the alarm after booting the device)

And check if your app is running or not:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4213851/284308

Comment: Thanksfor your message.