# Is that possible to open my application on reboot of android phone?

Tags: android, android-studio

I don't know much about android but I need to design an application where I need to start my application on reboot of android app over the first view screen so instead of loading the first screen I need to load my app. Is that possible to do?

If Yes, How?

Comment: Try using a service to open an activity of your app:
Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14385231/android-broadcastreceiver-auto-run-service-after-reboot-of-device)

Comment: Thanks Mas, and also I don't need the first page that opens up and I need my application to open